# SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CHAMPIONSHIPS": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

This is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE FavoriteBasketballTeams
    TeamName VARCHAR(255) Primary Key,
    DateCreated Date,
    Championships INT NOT NULL,
    FinalsAppearances INT NOT NULL ;
    
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Nets','1976','0','2');
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Thunder','1967','1','4');
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Lakers','1948','17','32');
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Trailblazers','1970','1','3');
```

And these are the errors I get:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE FavoriteBasketballTeams
    TeamName VARCHAR(255) Primary Key,
    DateCreated Date,
    Championships INT NOT NULL,
    FinalsAppearances INT NOT NULL
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 7 in command -
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Nets','1976','0','2')
Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 58
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CHAMPIONSHIPS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 8 in command -
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Thunder','1967','1','4')
Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 58
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CHAMPIONSHIPS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 9 in command -
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Lakers','1948','17','32')
Error at Command Line : 9 Column : 58
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CHAMPIONSHIPS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 10 in command -
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances) Values('Trailblazers','1970','1','3')
Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 58
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CHAMPIONSHIPS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Insert parentheses around field definitions in create table, to start with. Create Table FavBasketTeams (teamName ....). You can visit w3schools.com for basic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses after the table name and before the semi-column in the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FavoriteBasketballTeams(
    TeamName VARCHAR(255) Primary Key,
    DateCreated Date,
    Championships INT NOT NULL,
    FinalsAppearances INT NOT NULL
);
```

Then `'1976'` is a string literal and is not a date. Oracle tries to parse it to a date but its not in the correct format; you could use `TO_DATE('1976','YYYY')` but that would set the date's month to the current month of the year so its probably better to use a date literal `DATE '1976-01-01'` and set the month and day components to the start of the year (or do some research and set it to the actual day they were founded). Also, when you have a numeric column then you should not pass the value as a string, just use a number:

```sql
INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(
  TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances
) Values(
  'Nets',DATE '1976-01-01',0,2
);

INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(
  TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances
) Values(
  'Thunder', DATE '1967-01-01',1,4
);

INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(
  TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances
) Values(
  'Lakers', DATE '1948-01-01',17,32
);

INSERT INTO FavoriteBasketballTeams(
  TeamName,DateCreated,Championships,FinalsAppearances
) Values(
  'Trailblazers',DATE '1970-01-01',1,3
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76390b4c687b1ca2cc6df2943d46f93e)*